# Datadog AWS RDS monitoring storage used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, datadog

Setting up Datadog alert to monitor AWS RDS Aurora databased by percentage used. If the percentage of storage is above 80% alert. Using the following two metrics

```
A: aws.rds.free_local_storage
B: aws.rds.volume_bytes_used

a/b 

Alert if greater than 0.8
```

Is this possible in Datadog using the two metrics and diving them? or is their another way of achieving this in Datadog ?